# Filter JSON based on Backbone.js model keys

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection, that is pretty standard.

```
(function($){

  var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
  var DataCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: DataModel,
    url: 'assets/path_data.json'
  });
  var dataCollection = new DataCollection()
  dataCollection.fetch({
    reset:true
  });

  // Choice Model
  var ChoiceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
  var choiceModel = new ChoiceModel({
    froms: 'froms',
    tos: 'tos'
  })
```

I'm trying to carry out a function on JSONs that meet a specific criteria. I'm having two problems with this code.

```
for(var i=0, len=choiceModel.length; i<len; i++){
if (choiceModel[i].froms == a){
function geolines (a,b,f,g,h,j){
   };
  }
 }
```

1. The variable 'len' I believe is only counted as 2 for the two JSON keys in the Model. What notation should be used in order to make it the length of the number of JSONs that exist in the collection?
2. I don't believe my if statement is correct either. I know of a few ways to access JSON keys in JS, but none seem to work in my case. I've tried $.each, $.map and $.grep, they simply give me an empty array. What is the best way to iterate over all the JSON values that belong to the Key 'froms' and make sure they match a variable, in this case 'a'?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have this:

```
for(var i=0, len=choiceModel.length; i<len; i++){
```

Are you sure the Backbone Model has length attribute?
I am not very clear what JSON you want to iterate, but I think if you want to iterate the JSON of your collection above, you should iterate you collection, and then get 'form' attribute of every model. If you want to use a filter, just try to `collection.where(attributes)`method, see here: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where

Comment: That solved both of the problems perfectly, thank you so much!